# why Nginx server does not get started?

Tags: server, nginx

I'm new on nginx server. I installed nginx on my Ubuntu operating system using the command

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

and then tried to start the nginx web server using the command

```
 sudo service nginx start
```

and then tried to open the nginx web server on my web browser by typing the url `http://http://192.168.1.120/` (my ip address).

But this is showing a blank page. I don't know is there any mistakes in my procedures, can anyone help me to fix this?

```
nginx  -t
```

shows some **errors** like as follows  :

```
[alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/09/09 12:01:37 [warn] 9035#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2016/09/09 12:01:37 [emerg] 9035#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: What's the Ubuntu version you're using and what happens when you type `http://localhost/` in the browser. Also usually the service is started automatically after the install process and there's no need for the `service nginx start` command. And finally what's the output of `nginx -v` and `nginx -t`

Comment: my ubuntu version is 14.04 and when  i  type http://localhost/ which is showing an error 403 forbidden

Comment: nginx  -v  shows **nginx /1.4.6***

Comment: and nginx  -t shows some errors like as follows

Comment: A blank page would seem to indicate that nginx is working correctly.

Do you really get a blank page in the browser, and no error message?

Comment: Well, according to the error - there might be a problem in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and it would be useful if you post it's content here as well (and tell us if you've made any changes to it ). You also might want to post the contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` because it's included from `nginx.conf`

Comment: @SledgeHammer I find in newer version nginx don't have a sites-avaiable and sites-enabled anymore.

Comment: @tyan I'm not sure which newer versions you're referring to, but the default install on Ubuntu 16.04 still provides them.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I use nginx version 1.10.1 ubuntu repo update too slow.

Comment: @tyan `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` is an addition to the config made by Debian and is available only in the official Debian and Ubuntu repositories. It's never been a part of the official nginx repositories (or at least I've never seen it there so far).

Comment: @SledgeHammer yes , recently I when I update it I find the problem .so I'm going to stick with offical release for now on.